# How to remove /?_escaped_fragment from my website URL

Tags: html, duplicates, seo

I have HTML and CSS website. When I crawl my website on Seobility.net I receive this error:

> duplicate page and text

because I have two address form one page:

- 1 address is original page
- other address is original page with this parameter `https://www.example.com/about/?_escaped_fragment`

How can I remove that?

Answer (score 1):

it is good practice to put

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/originalpage.html">
```

in the head section of your html file. The seobility check gives you a hint in this direction.